# JSONPath range not working when using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

I'm accessing Kubernetes through the CLI tool `kubectl` and I'm trying to get a list of all context names, one per line.

I know that JSONPath can be used to extract and format specific output.  I get really close to what I want with

```sh
kubectl config view -o=jsonpath="{.contexts[*].name}"
```

but this puts all the names on the same line.  I'm trying to use `range` to list all names separated by newlines:

```sh
kubectl config view -o=jsonpath='{range .contexts[*]}{.name}{"\n"}{end}'
```

But this just gives me an error:

```
error: unexpected arguments: [.contexts[*]}{.name}{"\n"}{end}]
See 'kubectl config view -h' for help and examples.
```

I've reviewed the `kubectl` documentation and what I'm doing is really similar to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-by-pod, where the command is

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}' |\
sort
```

but I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Which version of kubectl are you using?

Comment: Checkout https://gist.github.com/so0k/42313dbb3b547a0f51a547bb968696ba

Comment: Kubectl version 1.13.1.  I am also running this in Windows Subsystem for Linux; not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had been using @ahmetb's [kubectl-aliases](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectl-aliases) script, which works fine with no problem, but one of the suggestions in the README was:

> Print the full command before running it: Add this to your .bashrc or .zshrc file:
>
> `function kubectl() { echo "+ kubectl $@"; command kubectl $@; }`

I had that function declaration in my .bashrc and it was stripping off the quotes for my `jsonpath` argument.  As soon as I commented out that declaration and opened a new shell, the command worked correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your command works for me in kubectl 1.9.2

If it still doesn't work, you can use tr in bash to replace spaces with new lines:

```
kubectl config view -o=jsonpath="{.contexts[*].name}" | tr " " "\n"
```